Select records from a table, where the results match all criterion in a sub-query
Example...
Create Table QryTable (ID [int], Description [nvarchar](255), CSV_Vals [nvarchar](255))
insert into QryTable
values
    (1, 'Description of record #1', 'val_1,val_2,val_3,val_4,val_5,val_6'),
    (2, 'Description of record #2', 'val_1,val_3,val_6,val_9,val_10,val_11'),
    (3, 'Description of record #3', 'val_2,val_3,val_4,val_15,val_20,val_21')

Create Table CriterionTbl (ID [int] identity (1,1), CriterionVals [nvarchar](50))
insert into CriterionTbl values ('val_3', 'val_4')

Functionality similar to:
Select *
from QryTable
where CSV_vals like `AND (SELECT CriterionVals from CriterionTbl)`

The results would be the same as if the query were written, except the independent values are the results of querying the CriterionVals table, and only records which include all values listed in the CriterionVals table are returned, rather than records which include any of the values in the CriterionVals table:
Select *
from QryTable
where CSV_vals like '%val_3%'
and  CSV_vals like '%val_4%'

I'm able to use the following query to get records with any value in the CriterionTbl, but I need to write a query which returns results of records that have all criterion from the CriterionTbl sub-query.
This is what I have that returns records with anything in the CriterionTbl:
select *
from QryTable
Join (select * from CriterionTbl as CT)
on QryTable.CSV_Vals like '%' + CT.CriterionVals + '%'

This returns: records 1, 2, and 3, becauuse 1,2, and 3 all have either 'val_3' or 'val_4'
But what I want is only records 1 and 3, because only 1 and 3 have 'val_3' and 'val_4'
But I need this to happen from the sub-query, so that the results are based on the contents of CriterionVals table.

Your insert commands are invalid. Is there one row only in the second table with two values or are there two rows with one value in each?

This fiddle might help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/AZzsprzJ

maybe this will help https://www.sqlshack.com/dynamic-sql-in-sql-server/

The root of the problem here is your design. You have violated 1NF by storing delimited data like this. If this was properly normalized this would be simple.

Usually, an any-criteria condition would be applied using WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Criteria WHERE criteria-passes) and an all-criteria condition can be applied using WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Criteria WHERE NOT criteria-passes).
For this case, I believe you need the latter:
select *
from QryTable QT
where not exists (
    select *
    from CriterionTbl CT
    where ',' + QT.CSV_Vals + ',' not like '%,' + CT.CriterionVals + ',%'
)

I added the commas to the above test to avoid false matches between strings like "val_2" and "val_20".
The ALL() operator can also be used, with a bit of coaxing and a CASE expression that maps a success or fail to a 1 or 0.
select *
from QryTable QT
where 1 = all (
    select case when ',' + QT.CSV_Vals + ',' like '%,' + CT.CriterionVals + ',%' then 1 else 0 end
    from CriterionTbl CT
)

It is worth noting that if CriterionTbl is empty, the condition will always be true.
The results are the same for both of the above:



ID
Description
CSV_Vals




1
Description of record #1
val_1,val_2,val_3,val_4,val_5,val_6


3
Description of record #3
val_2,val_3,val_4,val_15,val_20,val_21



See this db<>fiddle for a demo. (Thanks to @BartMcEndree for the initial fiddle set-up.)

It is a shame that it requires the use of double negation. It was hard to immediately understand why it works. I wish there was a more straight forward solution.

Sometimes it is good to know the distributive rules for boolean logic:  NOT(A AND B) = (NOT A OR NOT B),  NOT(A OR B) = (NOT A AND NOT B), and similarly ANY(X) = NOT ALL(NOT X) and ALL(X) = NOT ANY(NOT X). The latter applies here.

Or think of it as "everything passes" = "nothing failed".

Thanks, @TN for the solution. I provided a simplified version of what I'm working on, and the first solution you provided didn't work in my use-case, however the second one did:
select *
from QryTable QT
where 1 = all (
select case when ',' + QT.CSV_Vals + ',' like '%,' + CT.CriterionVals + ',%' then 1 else 0 end
from CriterionTbl CT
)
I'm trying to create a search query, where search terms are delimited in an input string with & for all criterion being required or + for any criterion being required.
Was able to user your 2nd solution to match against multiple fields

Note: though the first solution TN provided didn't work in my specific use-case, it did work in the example that I provided (which is a simplified version of my use-case). I think that the increased complexity of the data I'm querying, resulted in unexpected results from TN's first solution. So while it didn't work on my actual data-set, it does work perfectly for the example that I provided. Again, thanks TN!

See example. There we can use any suitable subquery instead of CriterionTbl as inner join (select x as CriterionVals  from anyTable ) as c.
select *
from(
  select q.* 
    ,row_number()over(partition by q.id order by q.id) rn
    ,count(*)over(partition by q.id) qty
  from QryTable q
  inner join CriterionTbl c 
    on concat(',',CSV_vals,',') like concat('%,',c.CriterionVals,',%')
)t
where qty=(select count(*) from CriterionTbl) and rn=1

There by calculationrow_number()over(partition by q.id order by q.id) rn we can get any 1 row from join result.
Value count(*)over(partition by q.id) qty - for filter rows, where all values from CtriterionTbl matches to CSV_vals.
We do not use distinct or group by for repetitive values in CriterionVals, because this does not affect the result.
Demo (on @TN example)
Or
select *
from(
select q.* 
  ,row_number()over(partition by q.id order by q.id) rn
from QryTable q
inner join CriterionTbl c 
  on concat(',',csv_vals,',') like concat('%,',c.criterionvals,',%')
)t
where rn=(select count(*) from CriterionTbl)


Thanks to everyone, @TN provided the solution that I was able to apply.
In my use-case, I am creating a stored procedure which will accept a parameter string with search terms separated by & or by +.
If separated by &, then each search term must be included in the result set.
If separated by + then one search term must be included in each result returned.
Using my simplified original table as an example, here is the complete solution I implemented:
Create Table QryTable (ID [int], Description [nvarchar](255), Vals_1 [nvarchar](255), Vals_2 [nvarchar](255), Vals_3 [nvarchar](255))
insert into QryTable
values
    (1, 'Description of record #1', 'val_1 val_2 val_3','val_4 val_5 val_6'),
    (2, 'Description of record #2', 'val_1 val_3 val_6','val_9 val_10 val_11'),
    (3, 'Description of record #3', 'val_2 val_3 val_4','val_15 val_20 val_21')
    (4, 'Description of record #4', 'val_2 val_5 val_9','val_15 val_20 val_21')
    (5, 'Description of record #5', 'val_2 val_8 val_5','val_15 val_20 val_21')
    (6, 'Description of record #6', 'val_2 val_6 val_11','val_1 val_20 val_3')

declare @AndOr int = 0
declare @Search_Table table (s_id int IDENTITY(1,1), searchTerm nvarchar(50))
--to return results with any term separated by + 
declare @SearchString nvarchar(255) = 'val_1+val_3+val7'
--to return results with all terms separated by &
declare @SearchString nvarchar(255) = 'val_1&val_3&val7'

IF CHARINDEX('&',@SearchString) > 0
    SET @AndOr =1; SET @SearchString = replace(@SearchString, '&&', '|')
IF CHARINDEX('+',@SearchString) > 0
    SET @SearchString = replace(@SearchString, '++', '|')
    
insert into @Search_Table SELECT    distinct value FROM string_split(@SearchString,'|') ST

if @AndOr = 0
    SELECT  *
    FROM    QryTable QT
    JOIN    @Search_Table ST
    ON  (       QT.Vals_1 LIKE '%' + ST.SearchString + '%'
            OR  QT.Vals_2 LIKE '%' + ST.SearchString + '%'
            OR  QT.Vals_3 LIKE '%' + ST.SearchString + '%'
        )
if @AndOr = 1
    SELECT  *
    FROM    QryTable QT
    WHERE   1=ALL   (
                        SELECT CASE WHEN QT.Vals_1 LIKE '%' + ST.SearchString + '%'
                        OR  QT.Vals_2 LIKE '%' + ST.SearchString + '%'
                        OR  QT.Vals_3 LIKE '%' + ST.SearchString + '%'
                        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                        FROM @Search_Table ST
                    )


This solution allows a user to enter a series of values to search, like: val_1&val_3&val_6, which would only return record 1 & 6.
However, if the user enters the string but replaces & with + val1+val_3+val_6, the return would be records: 1, 2, 3, 6
